# How to select shard for search query?

Tags: hibernate-search

I'm recently implemented ShardIdentifierProvider. It is working fine. But how to ensure it is using only one shared for query?

```
public class SiteIdAsShardIdProvider extends ShardIdentifierProviderTemplate {

@Override
protected Set<String> loadInitialShardNames(Properties properties, BuildContext buildContext) {
    ServiceManager serviceManager = buildContext.getServiceManager();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = serviceManager.requestService(HibernateSessionFactoryServiceProvider.class, buildContext);
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<String> ids = session.createSQLQuery("select cast(id as CHAR(3)) from website").list();
        return new HashSet<>(ids);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

@Override
public String getShardIdentifier(Class<?> entityType, Serializable id, String idAsString, Document document) {
    return document.getFieldable("siteId").stringValue();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating your own custom filter and overriding `getShardIdentifiersForQuery` should do the trick. Here is something that does approximately the same as what's in [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-filter-shard), but with a `ShardIdentifierProviderTemplate`:

```
@Override
public Set<String> getShardIdentifiersForQuery(FullTextFilterImplementor[] filters) {
    FullTextFilter filter = getFilterByName( filters, "customer" );
    if ( filter == null ) {
        return getAllShardIdentifiers();
    }
    else {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        result.add( filter.getParameter( "customerID" ) );
        return result;
    }
}

private FullTextFilter getFilterByName(FullTextFilterImplementor[] filters, String name) {
    for ( FullTextFilterImplementor filter: filters ) {
        if ( filter.getName().equals( name ) ) {
            return filter;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I created a ticket to update the documentation: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2513

Answer (score 0):

The shard selection at query time is controlled by using a custom Filter.

See ["5.3.1. Using filters in a sharded environment"](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-filter-shard) for details and examples.

Comment: IndexShardingStrategy is deprecated. I'm implemented ShardIdentifierProviderTemplate. Can I use ShardIdentifierProviderTemplate with Filter instead of IndexShardingStrategy?